# Windows 10 private net can't connect to the other peers, geth: 1.8.11

Tags: go-ethereum, windows, private

System information:

```
Geth version: Geth/1.8.11-unstable
OS & Version: WINDOWS10
```

I modified the main net Genesis config parameters in DefaultGenesisBlock in genesis.go,
and I replaced the MainnetBootnodes parameters with one line:
    enode://a4574b52d5ebc4414f1a55e656f66ca5647d891d5989e2bc3660141ec2c3fbed2dcd9bd50fc050915e3b8b96527f3fd9a8dfbcbdc9de3255fb948148ccd67603@192.168.2.210:30303

for learning Purpose.

Run geth.exe on 192.168.2.210 and 192.168.2.52.
The geth.exe on 2.52 can not connect to that on 2.210.
They are the same version that I build it. Cmd is "geth.exe console" with no other paras.
I've tried to use `admin.addPeer()` in geth and also failed.
net

```
{
  listening: true,
  peerCount: 0,
  version: "1",
  getListening: function(callback),
  getPeerCount: function(callback),
  getVersion: function(callback)
}
```

Comment: You don't get to modify the source code, you can just use `--bootnodes` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used `admin.addPeer("192.168.2.252")`.

To connect with other peers you need NodeUrl.

Try this, go to first node cmd

```
admin.nodeInfo.enode
```

gives you the enode url. Copy it and in the next peer node cmd use `admin.addPeer(NodeUrl)`

Comment: Yes, I tried to use admin.addPeer. But, still no peers:
( 6a606....57fb is my another pc with IP 192.168.1.101, and it is running a geth.exe )

> admin.addPeer("enode://6a606a7a6a81e2a48b8f00b3b24fcd0a6732f3b1ca7f86eb51087c24e7578cebb9638d7340a08534a2f396a9587a881f8ab31bfb86139abeeff
f5696766f57fb@192.168.1.101:30303")
true
> net
{
  listening: true,
  peerCount: 0,
  version: "1",
  ....
}
> admin
{
  datadir: "E:\\geth\\data",
  ....,
  peers: [],
  addPeer: function(),
 ....
}
>

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. It is due to the dao fork. The extradata validation does not pass cause the peers can't connect to each others.